# Multiple quotation marks in one line

Tags: javascript, quotes

I know that this is probably very dummy question, but I have been struggling with quotation marks for half an hour now:

I have a JS function that fills some div with content and there is an url which triggers another JS function which looks like this:

```
content = content.concat("<a href='#' onclick=\'highlight(\'" + value + "\')\'>" + conversationid + "</a>");
```

I tried various escaping etc, but I cant seem to get it right... This is how my attempt (the above code )actually looks like when I check it in browser:

```
<a href="#" onclick="highlight(" something")">something</a>
```

Can you suggest correct form please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ' in JS and " in HTML:

```
content = content.concat('<a href="#" onclick="highlight(\'' +
          value + '\')">' + conversationid + '</a>');
```

You don't need to escape " in a string when you use ' as delimitator

UPDATED: I did not realized that string is HTML and JS together, now it should work (added some escaped single quotes in the onclick attribute declaration)

Comment: This works when placed in html but the single quotes are somehow rewritten in the final result when used in JS.. i will have to work around it...

Comment: Your code on my page produces this: <a href="#" onclick="highlight(" 939-354-374")">939-354-374</a> ... I have no idea why

Comment: You were right, there is HTML with quoted JS with -again- quoted text, so you need to escape some single quotes. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

I realise i edited this rather alot but finally, i think it is the winner:

```
content = content.concat('<a href="#" onclick="highlight(\'' + value + '\')">' + conversationid + '</a>');
```

Edit as an alternative maybe you could pop the quotes as html?

```
content = content.concat('<a href="#" onclick="highlight(&#39;' + value + '&#39;)">' + conversationid + '</a>');
```

I think both will work :P

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LT6bC/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is rewriting your single-quotes to double-quotes. If you can't stop it, you'll have to work around it. Assign the value string to a variable, and embed the name of the variable instead of trying to quote the string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Javascript you can use singe qiotes to denote strings, so your function call in the HTML **should** look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="highlight(' something')">something</a>
```

HTML, on the other hand, requires you to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
content = content.concat("<a href="#" onclick="highlight('" + conversationid + "')>" + conversationid + "</a>");
```